# Need some help making an undo button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, undo

I'm pretty new to Swift and iOS development, so I'm kind of stuck on this one problem. I made this app that changes the background color of an image view square whenever a button is pressed. The colors are randomly selected from the RGB spectrum. Now I need an undo button that sets the background color to the previous color.

Here's what I've got so far.

```swift
var previousColor: UIColor?
    @IBAction func didPressRandomButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let randomRed = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
        let randomGreen = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
        let randomBlue = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
        let color = UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1)
        previousColor = color
        imageDisplay.backgroundColor = color
    }
    @IBAction func didPressUndoButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if previousColor != nil{
            imageDisplay.backgroundColor = previousColor!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does not work? The logic looks correct. And you `if let previousColor = previousColor` instead https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: Just a guess, because you haven't really told us what the issue is. Is it crashing on your force-unwrap of `previousColor`? Or are you getting a `nil` value for something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's not clear from your question, I'm guessing that you need the color to change on pressing RANDOM button and the undo the change on pressing the UNDO button.

The problem here seems to be that you are overwriting the previousColor when you press RANDOM button. Try doing this instead

```
   var previousColor: UIColor?
        
   @IBAction func didPressRandomButton(_ sender: Any) {

            previousColor = imageDisplay.backgroundColor

            let randomRed = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
            let randomGreen = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
            let randomBlue = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
            
            let color = UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1)
          
            imageDisplay.backgroundColor = color
   }

   @IBAction func didPressUndoButton(_ sender: Any) {
            if previousColor != nil{
                imageDisplay.backgroundColor = previousColor!
            }
            
   }
```